# Scaling along normals in Geometry Nodes

Tags: transforms, normals, mathematics, geometry-nodes

I'm trying to use geometry nodes to scale up a duplicate mesh along each faces' normal to "thicken" up the mesh. This can be achieved manually by scaling a mesh with Alt+S (Scale along face normals).

This picture (green) shows what I'm trying to achieve through the Geometry Nodes (manually scaled along face normals):
[image: Scale Along Face Normals]

Here is an example of why a simple transform won't achieve the effect I'm going for:
[image: Normal Transform]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to _scale_ along normals, or _extrude_ along normals?

Comment: Just looking to scale

Comment: what would be the difference to scale the mesh!?

Comment: since now 2 people don't understand what you mean you should include some screenshots/paintings what you want to have

Comment: Adjusted my question to try and clarify what exactly I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @BenignBrett Such an effect can be achieved by just adding a solidify modifier and setting the offset on it to 1, if thats what you mean.

Comment: I am actually trying to scale up a duplicate mesh created through the geometry nodes. If there was a way to add/adjust modifiers to geometry through  nodes that would be a potential solution

Comment: @BenignBrett So you mean that you want to scale up a mesh that is a duplicate of another mesh (which is actually duplicated using geometry nodes). Am I right?

Comment: Yes. My use case is that in a geometry node I am grabbing all objects in a collection, duplicating them, and scaling them all up along their normals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this it?

2 *Attribute Vector Math* nodes, and 1 temporary attribute to hold the offset.

[image]

'Scale' along normals might (strictly) be a misnomer... Solidify,  Displace, and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> all *translate* vertices along normals.

In GN 'Fields', (Blender 3.0+) that would be:

[image]

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: "Warning: This node is considered legacy and will be removed in Blender 4.0.": https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attribute/attribute_vector_math.html  Also, I can't find it in Blender 3.0...

Comment: @JohanWalles Thanks! Edited. Must root out all pre-Fields GN answers.